# Schema attribute of @SequenceGenerator does not work in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

There is an oracle user where some objects are common between other users.
Due to this fact, the `application.yml` is like this following:

```
jpa:
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        default_schema: common_user
        show_sql: true
```

Any objects such as `Entity` that must be in its own user is declared with `schema` attribute of @Table-annotation like this following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NET_EVL_TEMPLATE", schema = "NET")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "SEQ_NET_EVL_TEMPLATE", allocationSize = 1)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Evaluation extends BaseEntity<Long> {
...
```

This scenario is worked rightly for `Table` but it is not worked for `sequence`; another hand all sequence of all user is generated in the common user.
I put schema in the sequence attribute like this:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "SEQ_NET_EVL_TEMPLATE_TREE", allocationSize = 1, schema = "NET")
```

But it again does not work and it again is generated in the common user.

How do I fix my problem? Another hand the sequence-object of any user is generated to its own user instead of common user.

Comment: A more normal post would be "I tried this metadata and this DDL was generated, and then I tried this metadata and this DDL was generated. I was expecting this". When you post what DDL was generated for your 2 sets of metadata then you have basis for a question

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. After this I will write posts with the right structure.

Comment: why not start by EDITING your post now, because until you do you provide no debugging for anyone to comment on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set schema name to sequence name like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NET_EVL_TEMPLATE", schema = "NET")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "NET.SEQ_NET_EVL_TEMPLATE", allocationSize = 1)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Evaluation extends BaseEntity<Long> {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's an issue. You need to replicate it with this test case template and open a Jira issue:

http://in.relation.to/2018/06/04/best-way-write-hibernate-orm-issue-test-case/

Comment: When is it fixed?

Comment: Unless you provide a replicating test case that proves it, there's no issue to fix.